# How can I get epigrapf on a page without `1.1 TITLE` left over from the previous section?

Tags: sectioning, epigraphs

Epigraph would appear on a page under the previous section's heading in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{preface}
    \section{title}
    \lipsum

    \clearpage
    \epigraph{text}{source}

    \chapter{main chapter}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to remove the section heading from that page?

[image]

Comment: Uhm... that error looks similar to one I have when I use `epigraph` in the standard class `book`. There is a short code for fix it, but I see you're using `memoir`. If you don't use epigraph, that header appears? Between the native options of `memoir` is there no ona that avoid the usage of that package?

Comment: @Aradnix Good catch, but I realized that even w/o using `epigraph` explicitly the heading is still there. So editing out from MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First approach

Well, this MWE works for me:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{preface}
    \section{title}
    \lipsum

    \clearpage \pagestyle{plain}
    \epigraph{text}{source}

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{main chapter}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if you must to change the `\pagestyle` again before the main chapter. Try it.

---

### Addenda

You have misunderstood me. I do not pretend that restructure your book. The division macros for organize a book does not really affect your problem, but they helps to solve them.

The problem, from what I see, is that when you try to put a epigraph on a blank page, `memoir` (like the standard classes) keeps the head of the chapter or previous section, which is undesirable.

I don't know if you have that same problem in chapters that end in odd page, if you always open the chapters on odd page (recto). If you open them in any page then you will not notice.

My suggestion then is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document} 
        \frontmatter
        \chapter{Preface}
        \section{title}
        \lipsum

        \newpage 
        \pagestyle{plain}
        \epigraph{text}{source}           

        \chapter{Another stuff} 
        \lipsum

        \mainmatter
        \pagestyle{headings} 

        \chapter{The first one}
        \lipsum
    \end{document}
```

The problem has to do with the page style, I don't know how to use `memoir`, also I don't know if like [KOMA Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) incorporates its own system, otherwise it may be convenient to use a package like [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) which define headers such and how you want to use. With that you can correct this error.

In the meantime, try the above code. It should run you, works for me. All I do is define a style blank page without headers or footers to your page headings: `\pagestyle{plain}`, and then later go back to a page with header style: `\pagestyle{headings}`. The `headings` option will give you the look by default, if you use `fancyhdr` maybe you can use the option `myheadings` inside `\pagestyle{}`.

Try to run the code with `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` and without them and check the result.

Comment: Unfortunately the next chapter is still a `frontmatter`

Comment: @ajeh there is not problem then.

Comment: Yes, there is, as I cannot put `\mainmatter` where you have.

Comment: You can put it later or avoid it if `memoir` doesn't use it.

Comment: @ajeh Do you understand why I added `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`?

Comment: You addeded `\mainmatter` to clear the heading of the previous section. I cannot follow your example, as my `\chapter{main chapter}` would still be `\frontmatter`. I agree, it was a bad naming on my part.

Comment: @ajeh That's wrong. A book material is organized typically in 3 parts: frontmatter is the material before your chapters: Titlepage, legal page, agreements, acknowledge, preface, table of contents, etc. The mainmatter is in fact the core of the book, the chapters you wrote. The last part is the backmatter, where you can put the references, appendixes, the index, afterwords, and all that stuff. Since you're creating a book or something else... this macros help (at least in the standard book class) to organize better the book. Perhaps memoir uses something different. I don't know.

Comment: @ajeh In the sixth chapter of the documentation of the class memoir, there is an explanation about what I explained before. And in the chapter 13th is an explanation of the epigraphs. Take a look to see how it works.

Comment: We can argue about organization of material, but that is not helpful, as all I need is an epigraph on a clear page. That epigraph is in the middle of front matter and it is not going to change.

Comment: @ajeh We don't need to argue, you misunderstood me. Please check the answer again and check the `memoir` documentation.

Comment: `\pagestyle{plain}` did the trick, no need to play with `\mainmatter`

Comment: @ajeh I told you since the first time. If you don't need more headers after your epigraph, then `\pagestyle` does the trick. If not you'll need something more sophisticated.